# Changing position of d3 svg box in browser window

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a form that, when submit is clicked, generates an svg using d3 (after deleting the old svg already present). How can I make it so that the svg is on the upper left portion of the browser window, and not underneath the form? Here's the code that deletes then generates a new svg on each submit.

```
//(form)
//(function call on form submit)

d3.select("#thesvg").remove();
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", w + m[1] + m[3])
    .attr("height", h + m[0] + m[2])
    .attr("id", "thesvg")
    .append("svg:g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + m[0] + ")");
```

w, h and m are width, height and margins, respectively.

I think I might have to use some sort of style tag, but I couldn't find any style information in the d3 wiki on github. More generally, is there more d3 information that's geared a bit towards graphics-newbies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
```

This selects the body and appends the svg to the end so it appears at the end of the content.

If you replace "body" with an id of say a div element it will append the svg to that div.  The div can then be placed where you want.

```
d3.select("#id").append("svg:svg")
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly! I didn't 100% understand what the "body" part meant and I was largely copying it. I figured it meant some sort of larger space on the page. I put a div at the top and connected it to it and it worked great.